# GPIB low-level programming

Tags: gpib

Very ancient device. According to the manual, GPIB commands looks like this:

```
IFC|REN|ATN|DIO7|DIO6|DIO5|DIO4|DIO3|DIO2|DIO1 ||
0  |1  |0  |1   |0   |0   |0   |1   |1   |1
```

For GPIB trying to use this manual

https://csi.pl/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/GPIBProgrammingReferenceManual.pdf

On page 13 it says I can do low-level routines.

So how do I program this device? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to describe your setup better. If you are attempting to control from a PC, then the quickest solution is to buy a GPIB card or adapter for your PC. GPIB is also known as IEEE-488. Then you can communicate using the parallel character based protocol. If you have more time than money, then you could generate the GPIB signals yourself with a parallel interface.

Comment: I have GPIB adapter. I don't understand how do I program that IFC REN ATN...

Comment: Did you get driver software with the adapter? IFC, REN, ATN are handshake signals. The adapter HW/SW will take care of those, you just send and receive characters.

Comment: I think so too. So I need to send that commands IFC, REN, ATN and then send data DIO7, DIO6, DIO5... I need an example.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59151499/gpib-communication-with-python-pyvisa/67085778#67085778) Stackoverflow Q&A might apply. First thing is check if the bit manipulations needed are the same as the ones that became standard in later instruments. If they are, then you just use the `read()` or `write()` functions in your GPIB or VISA library and don't worry about the bit manipulations. Only if the bit pattern is non-standard do you have to worry about coding it directly.

Comment: Bit pattern is non-standard. Thats why I need to send bits directly.

Comment: PyVisa (and the underlying VISA library) have functions `control_atn`, `control_ren`, `send_ifc` as methods of the GPIBInterface class. Have you tried using those?

Answer (score 0):

On a modern PC, you should use a VISA library from Keysight, NI etc. There are also an open source VISA and Python bindings (PyVISA). This will allow you to access the device from your PC. The 1st thing you will be able to do is to send an *IDN?\n command to the device and get a response.

Comment: There are `USB to GPIB` dongles (Prologix makes them.) But just toys. Not real-world. For example, there’s no interrupt channel there. So SRQs aren't implemented or are poorly implemented. Care is need to get hands on really good HPIB hardware interface into the PCI ecosystem. (PCI, for example, only supports burst mode and not full, continuous mode DMA.) You mention Keysight (for example, [this](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/82350C/high-performance-pci-gpib-interface-card.html).) Some thought will be required, still. None of this is slam-dunk. I imagine, anyway.

Comment: Yes, all of those points are correct, but not relevant to the OP - They wanted to communicate with the device. My assumption is that they have the adapter, and trying to use it at the lowest level possible.

Comment: @periblepsis Keysight and NI also make USB-GPIB dongles. And have pretty much stopped making (desktop) PCI ones except at absurd price points.

Comment: @ThePhoton PCI isn't a win even if it costs. Neither USB nor PCI can support all HPIB transactions. The system I use and maintain is a 486DX based motherboard that doesn't use PCI. (Didn't exist.) PCI was introduced about a year before the Pentium and marketed as 'green' because of the reflection wave technology (but the reasons Intel had were nothing about that.) But once the southbridge was introduced and failed to fully support ISA transactions, I decided to keep the 486DX operational. It's what I use for my Tektronix GPIB instruments here (PS2520G, for example.) ISA supports HPIB.

Comment: @periblepsis if you're trying to do real-time control or capture video over HPIB, maybe you need to go to all that trouble. For just controlling a straightforward instrument that needs a few dozen commands sent and a few 100 or 1000 bytes of data read every second or so, USB-GPIB works fine.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah. I just wanted to maintain a system where I ***know*** that everything an HPIB can dish out or accept can be supported. I hate it when something goes awry and I spend 3 days of profoundly and totally wasted personal time tracking down the fact that a transaction I couldn't possibly have known, a priori, would be used, was needed, and wasn't supported; only afterwards to discover what I already know would happen, once I finally pin down the problem. Better to just keep a working system that *"just always works right."* Life is just too short for this kind of crap.